# send excel file as base64 via using WhatsApp api with Ultramsg

Tags: whatsapp

I am trying to convert excel file to base64 to send WhatsApp API with [Ultramsg](https://ultramsg.com)  :

```
<?php

require_once ('vendor/autoload.php'); // if you use Composer
//require_once('ultramsg.class.php'); // if you download ultramsg.class.php
$token=""; // Ultramsg.com token
$instance_id=""; // Ultramsg.com instance id
$client = new UltraMsg\WhatsAppApi($token,$instance_id);
$to=""; 
$filename="test.xlsx"; 
$document = base64_encode(file_get_contents("test.xlsx"));
$api=$client->sendDocumentMessage($to,$filename,$document);
print_r($api);
```

But I see this error :

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [document] => file extension not supported
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add MIME types for Microsoft Excel
.xls=application/vnd.ms-excel
or
.xlsx=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

```
$document ="data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,".$document;
```

So , Try this code block and enjoy (: :

```
<?php
require_once ('vendor/autoload.php'); // if you use Composer
//require_once('ultramsg.class.php'); // if you download ultramsg.class.php
$token=""; // Ultramsg.com token
$instance_id=""; // Ultramsg.com instance id
$client = new UltraMsg\WhatsAppApi($token,$instance_id);
$to=""; 
$filename="test.xlsx"; 
$document = base64_encode(file_get_contents("test.xlsx"));
$document ="data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,".$document;
$api=$client->sendDocumentMessage($to,$filename,$document);
print_r($api);
```